# Retrieving a formula with VLOOKUP from table with row numbers pointing to another sheet

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I would like to create a table with products and formulas on a sheet (Sheet2). For different products, different formulas apply.
I would like to retrieve the formula from that table but use the row numbers from the row in Sheet1

How do I enter a formula which is evaluated with the correct row numbers from Sheet1.

I have a UDF eval that can evaluate a text string:

```
=eval(vlookup(Product;Table;2;false)
```

The formula retrieved from the Table should use the row number of the actual row that the eval() is on.

I tried the following:

```
="D"&ROW(Sheet2!$A16)&"/G"&ROW(Sheet2!$A16)&"/F"&ROW(Sheet2!$A16)&"*5"
```

This retrieves the formula but the eval() does not calculate the result.

Comment: So the table on Sheet2 contains the formulas that need to be executed on Sheet1. I want to retrieve the formula with a VLOOKUP and use that formula in the row on Sheet1.
The challenge is to get the correct row number in the formula retrieved from the table with the VLOOKUP.

Another option would be to use a nested IF with the correct formula for each Product; this is less easy to maintain if a new Product is added to the table.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, *product* is located on Sheet2 in the 16<sup>th</sup> row of the first column of *table*. If you want the 16<sup>th</sup> row on the worksheet, you can use the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) on a full column reference, discarding the [structured references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-F5ED2452-2337-4F71-BED3-C8AE6D2B276E) of the [ListObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174247.aspx) *table* or you can use MATCH on the structured table reference and compensate for the *'position within'* *table* by adjusting by the *table* header row.

That's probably confusing so here is an example.

[image: table_row_lookup]

To find the actual row-on-the-worksheet where **bcd** resides you would use one of these formulas.

```
=MATCH("bcd", Sheet2!B:B, 0)
=MATCH("bcd", Table2[a], 0)+ROW(Table2[#Headers])
```

The first simply returns row **6** on the worksheet. The second returns **2** since bcd is in the second row of the ListObject's [.DataBodyRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.databodyrange.aspx) and this is adjusted by the row that the [.HeaderRowRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.listobject.headerrowrange.aspx) is in; e.g. 2 + 4 = 6.

Now that everything is clear, all you need to do is use the result from one of those formulas as the *row_number* parameter in an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a).

```
=INDEX(D:D, MATCH("bcd", Sheet2!B:B, 0))/
 INDEX(G:G, MATCH("bcd", Sheet2!B:B, 0))/
 INDEX(F:F, MATCH("bcd", Sheet2!B:B, 0))*5
'or,
=INDEX(D:D, MATCH("bcd", Table2[a], 0)+ROW(Table2[#Headers]))/
 INDEX(G:G, MATCH("bcd", Table2[a], 0)+ROW(Table2[#Headers]))/
 INDEX(F:F, MATCH("bcd", Table2[a], 0)+ROW(Table2[#Headers]))*5
```

[image: match_table_row]

Your own formula could have worked with a series of [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd)s that convert constructed strings to actual cell references. However, INDIRECT is considered volatile and best avoided if possible.

```
=INDIRECT("D"&ROW(Sheet2!$A6))/INDIRECT("G"&ROW(Sheet2!$A6))/INDIRECT("F"&ROW(Sheet2!$A6))*5
```

Comment: Hi Jeeped, I understand the MATCH and INDIRECT as well as the INDEX but maybe I did not specify exactly enough what I want.

Comment: In the table on Sheet2 I would like to specify the formula that need to be calculated for each Product.
The row number in these formulas should change/adapt to the actual row in Sheet1 where, based on a VLOOKUP(), the correct row number should be used to do the math.

The Product exists multiple times on Sheet1. Maybe I could send you an exaple sheet?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on the capability of Excel to reference the cells in R1C1 style. In order to use it, you will have to go to File -> Options -> "Formulas" tab, and check the box "R1C1 reference style" in "Working with Formulas" group.
In addition, your *eval()* function will have to be able to evaluate such kind of formulas.

Once, all of these is done, you only have to retrieve the formula.
In order to make the things clear, I will focus on an example.

The table below is the contents of Sheet1 (the "Database" of products). 
[image: sheet1]

The column "Formula" contains the relevant formula: 
for apple: RC[-2]+RC[-1] 
for banan: RC[-2]*RC[-1] 
for lemon: RC[-2]/RC[-1]

The table below is the contents of Sheet2:
[image: Sheet2]

 The column "Formula" here contains the formula, retrieved from Sheet1. The formula of the column "Formula" is as follows:

```
=FORMULATEXT(INDEX(Sheet1!R2C1:R4C4,MATCH(RC[-3],Sheet1!R2C1:R4C1,0),4))
```

The description of each of the functions, used here (*formulatext*, *index* and *match*) can be found in Excel help.

As it can be seen, the retrieved formula, represented in R1C1 style is correct in context of Sheet2, were the products are arranged differently, and may appear more than once. The only remaining work to do is to apply the *eval()* function, after it was adapted to evaluate R1C1-style referenced formulas.

I hope it helps.

Comment: So the table on Sheet2 contains the formulas that need to be executed on Sheet1. I want to retrieve the formula with a VLOOKUP and use that formula in the row on Sheet1.
The challenge is to get the correct row number in the formula retrieved from the table with the VLOOKUP.

Another option would be to use a nested IF with the correct formula for each Product; this is less easy to maintain if a new Product is added to the table.

Comment: In R1C1 style the challenge to get the correct row number is worked around. Note, that the formulas in Sheet2 refer to the correct row. Near "apple" in Sheet2 is "RC[-2]+RC[-1]", which means "go to the cell placed on same row, two columns left and add it to the cell on the same row, one column to the left".